# How to query the Account Balance of Alice in a substrate node?

Tags: rust, substrate

Using the polkadot UI, I can see the account Balances of `Alice`, `Bob`, displayed in the Accounts tab.

Using `Developer> ChainState`, I can query the storage on ("Balances" "TotalIssuance"), but there seems to be no content in ("Balances", "Account", alice_account_id)
I'm using substrate `branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24"`

Alternative, I can get the "Balance", "TotalIssuance" using `polkadot.js.org/apps` connected locally via browser extension.

[image]

So, where is the total balance of accounts like Alice stored if not in ("Balances", "Account")?

Comment: just a suggestion: use https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ to ask questions about substrate, as it's far more active for these type of questions

Comment: What about system .Account Info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually stored in the Storage map
("System", "Account", <alice_account_id>).

```json
AccountInfoGen {
            nonce: 3,
            consumers: 0,
            providers: 1,
            sufficients: 0,
            data: AccountDataGen {
                free: 1142921504349461553,
                reserved: 0,
                misc_frozen: 0,
                fee_frozen: 0,
            },
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go in Developer > ChainState > Storage> System > AccountId